# Laravel Jensseger Mongodb belongsToMany additional fields

Tags: laravel, mongodb, has-and-belongs-to-many, jenssegers-mongodb, moloquent

the documentation says
"The belongsToMany relation will not use a pivot "table", but will push id's to a related_ids attribute instead. This makes the second parameter for the belongsToMany method useless. If you want to define custom keys for your relation, set it to null"

Then how can i set additional fields on related_ids attributes?

I have products and a cart,

here is a subdocument of cart about related_ids

product_id: [
'600ed36d5e2720122c633172',
'600ed3e792a0e87c86741eb2',
'600ed3f1bc85983ebc06fc53',
'600edcdfccfc896fe81fc262',
'600edd71bc665d23a03558c2'
],

but i need to set quantity for each product

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this?